# ODBC Driver Manager VBA Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I'm having some error pertaining to ODBC Driver Manager Data source name found. Just to give you a background, We're using this macro on Excel 2010 and was starting to test this on Office 365 when I'm starting to see this error. Upon checking ODBC is already installed under 64bit platform. Basically this macro is connected to a text file on which it gets that data.
Sample Code:

```
ConnCSV.Open "Driver={Microsoft Text Drvier (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" & path & ";Extensions=a,asxc,csv,tab,txt;HDR=NO;Persist Security Info=False"
```

I've tried to use Microsoft Access Text Driver still with no avail.

Greatly appreciated on any help on this.

Comment: Just to be clear, are we talking vb.net or vba here?  Similar syntax, but very different tools

Comment: Sorry my bad, was referring to VBA Excel

Comment: can I use other query instead to connect the txt file on VBA?